# Where Will I Get Apache Hama-0.6.2 or Older version of HAMA?

Tags: hadoop, hama

Can anyone provide me any link to apache hama 0.6.2 or earlier release? I am getting 0.6.3 only in the official site. But i need the earleir versions

Answer (score 1):

You can find it in maven repo.
http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22org.apache.hama%22%20AND%20a%3A%22hama-core%22